# Найти только русские слова/выражения с пробелами, но не отдельно стоящие пробелы

Tags: регулярные-выражения

В тексте "Приехал я на дачу Hello my Friend Как погода" должен найти "Приехал я на дачу " и "Как погода"

Пытался так: `[а-яёА-ЯЁ ]+`

Но выдает также отдельно стоящие пробелы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`([а-яёА-ЯЁ]+\s)+` вам не подойдёт?

Comment: @Эникейщик серьёзно? )

Comment: Нет на самом деле, но как удалить непонятно.

Comment: `([а-яёА-ЯЁ]+\s?)+` Вот так подошло)